# Error in GWT compilation

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction

I am compiling my project in GWT with any target . I get the following error on Linux and Solaris . I can compile the Samples which came with GWT but get this error .

I am using GWT 2.0.3 and JDK 1.6.17

```
 [java] Compiling module com.calix.ex1.webgui.ex1embeddedclient.Ex1EmbeddedGui
 [java] [ERROR] Unexpected
 [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$FindTypesInCud.visit(JdtCompiler.java:179)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1253)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:478)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReturnStatement.traverse(ReturnStatement.java:262)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:239)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1350)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1223)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:158)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:467)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:142)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:281)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:182)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:280)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:502)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:414)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:201)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an answer here : [GWT Issue 4552](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4552)

> If you neglect to add an import for an
>   anonymous class like so:

```
FocusPanel dropdown = new FocusPanel();
dropdown.addClickHandler(new BloggiDiBlook() {});
```

> where class BloggiDiBlook **is neither
>   in the enclosing class's package, nor 
>   imported in the enclosing class's**
>   .java file. There ought to be an 
>   appropriate "Class not found" or
>   similar compiler error. Instead, the
>   JDT  Compiler throws the following
>   NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks for your help , the error looks same , but how will javac can compile this kind of missing imports ? I will search through the code to find if we have such cases .

Comment: I foundout the problem . Even enabling the trace of GWT compiler did not help so i just took the jdt compiler code and debugged using it. Anyway the problem was we had two inner classes . And one class referring another from the debugger i could see the type it was trying to load. 

thanks for your help !!